# Compare two files in Jpanel

Tags: java

Im trying to do a GUI program that will take two files and compare it

and  If they are match its will display match , and if not it will display the different lines between the two files.

my Question is how I'm gonna fined the different lines between the two files
and how i will print the result in the panel ?

```
public class Q25 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    File file1;
    File file2;
    JButton compare=new JButton("Compare");
    JButton fileButton = new JButton("First File");
    JButton fileButton1 = new JButton("Secound File");
     JLabel labelA;

    Q25()
    {
        add(fileButton);
        add(fileButton1);
        fileButton.addActionListener(this);
        fileButton1.addActionListener(this);

        add(compare);

        labelA = new JLabel();
        labelA.setText( "\n\n\n\n result : " );

        add(labelA);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource()==fileButton) 
        {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(Q25.this);
            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                if (!chooser.getSelectedFile().canRead())
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"The file is NOT readable by the current application!","ERROR" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );

            }
        }

        if(e.getSource()==fileButton1) 
        {
            JFileChooser chooser1 = new JFileChooser();
            int option1 = chooser1.showOpenDialog(Q25.this);
            if (option1 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                if (!chooser1.getSelectedFile().canRead())
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The file is NOT readable by the current application!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );

            }
        }


        if(file1==file2)
        {

        }else{

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("compare files ");
        frame1.add(new Q25());
        frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(250, 400);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should narrow down what you're having a problem with. Solve the issue step by step. E.g. start by determining whether two files are equal, then expand to listing all lines that differ, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Files.readAllBytes()` to get an array of bytes, then compare them with `Arrays.equals()`.
For example:

```
byte[] file1Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1);
byte[] file2Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file2);
if(Arrays.equals(file1Bytes, file2Bytes){
    //match
}
else{
    //no match
}
```

Keep in mind, this will return no match if the files appear identical but one contains an extra newline at the end, for example.

Now, for displaying the result; that's as simple as making a `JLabel` and updating its contents with `label.setText("whatever")`.